# Android touch event handling for overlapping child views

Tags: android, view, touch

My question is about the ordering for which onTouchEvent is called on child views when they overlap and the touch happens on the overlapped region.

I know that if there is no overlapping child views, then the ordering is simply from the target (the inner most view that is touched) all the way bubbling up the view root along its ancestor path.

However, what happens if the touch location is on overlapping views? That could happen for inner most View (not ViewGroup), or it could happen for ViewGroup as well if they overlap within parent ViewGroup. And things can get pretty complex really quickly.

I am writing some sample program to test a few interesting cases, but I'd like to know is there any general knowledge about it that can cross-validate with my empirical findings.

Comment: one overlapping view will always be on top of the other.  This is the view that will get the touch event.

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out myself. See the blog post: http://xiaolong-android.blogspot.com/2015/05/order-of-touch-event-dispatch-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've dealt with this, but if memory serves correctly, what happens is the top view in the z-order gets the touch event first. It has the option of handling the event, or passing it lower in the z-order. 
If it handles the event, then in its onTouchListener's "[onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent))" event, it returns true. At that point, the event has been consumed and will not be passed along to views behind it. If it returns false, that touch even will be passed along to the next view.